# What is the .get() method equivalent to query firebase in typescript using firebase functions, when using a realtime database?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am looking to fetch from firebase using typescript in cloud functions. I have looked here and found the bellow code, but am unsure if this is how you fetch or not (and am currently not able to test it).

```
   const usersRef = admin.database().ref('/users');

   return usersRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
         const uid = childSnapshot.key;
         promises.push(usersRef.child(uid + '/checker/update_available').set(true));
      });
```

I also looked in firebases documentation on this and could not find the info.

I used to use this:

```
    admin.database().ref('PeopleWhoFollowMe/\(uid)').get()
```

but I am getting an error: there is no `.get()` for this.

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the method for Realtime Database is `once()`.  It returns a promise just like Firestore's `get()`, so you don't need to provide a callback method to it.  The returned promise will contain the snapshot.